# MongoDB restapi for Android

Tags: android, mongodb

I write a android app and i use mongoDB. But i have a problem.

I wanna use RestApi. But when i use,  i cant parse this text.

If i write Mozilla. i see corretly.  ( [ { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5563962ae4b01374806901b2"} , "template_name" : "Game"} ]  )

But i cant parse

I try JSONObject but give an error.Error messages :

**Value [{ "_id" :{"$oid":"5563962ae4b01374806901b2"},"template_name":"Game"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject**

```
        restapiConnect apirest=new restapiConnect();//This variable my api access class
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

        String docUrl=apirest.getDocumentQuery("templates","'template_name':'Game'");
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(docUrl);
        String text = null;
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);


        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);

        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(text);
        template=new String[1];
        text = obj.getString("template_name");
```

Error only JSONObject line

```
public class restapiConnect{
public String getDocumentQuery(String col,String query)    {

    return getURL() + "databases/" + getDatabase() + "/collections/" + col + "?q=" + URLEncoder.encode("{" + query + "}")+"&apiKey=" + getApi();
}}
```

I create other method( geturl() , getdatabase() ). There isnt error this class.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error becouse

**[{ "_id" :{"$oid":"5563962ae4b01374806901b2"},"template_name":"Game"}]**

this is JSONArray not JSONObject

so you need to create JSONArray object and then getJSONObject fron it.

```
        text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);

        JSONArray array=new JSONArray(text);
        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(0);
```

hope this will work

Comment: give an error. "Content has been consumed"  @Gaurav-Polekar

Comment: exaclty on which line you get error?
or try this
`text = text.subString(1,text.length()-2);`
`JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(text);`